# Feedparser.parse etag and modified params

Tags: python, etag, feedparser

```python
import feedparser

d = feedparser.parse('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss', etag=d.etag)
```

I am new to Python and can't get my head around the parameter `etag=d.etag`
I Don't understand the data type. It's important to me because I am trying to make this parameter as a string dynamically. Does not work. I printed `type(d.etag)`, result is Unicode. So I tried to the Unicode func to form my string. Still no luck. Sorry, I realise this is so basic, I just can't get it. I know, to get the etag working is easy to achieve if you follow the examples from the feedparser site, where you do your first call without a param, then each subsequent call use the `etag=d.etag`. I am mainly learning on my iPad and am using Pythonista, so I am running my program over and over. I also know I could write it out to a file, and parse the file instead, but I really want to understand why I can't dynamically create this param. I am sure I will hit the same problem with another module sooner or later.

Comment: Can you make it a bit more clear what you're asking for? Your post is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved it now, but i don't understand why. I guess this is why my question was so unclear.
The answer was just to write etag=my_variable. So simple, but I was thrown because I don't get why the interpreter does not complain about etag=. It's not quoted. Maybe feedparser exposes something. I don't know, my head is spinning

Comment: Ok, that was embarrassing. I see now that etag=.... Is just a named argument for the function. Was just overwhelmed, trying to do too many things to soon in my learning cycle. I know everyone says Python is super easy to learn, but a lot of other related things you also must learn concurrently.